# Remove "space symbol"

Tags: spacing, symbols, listings

I'm trying to write:

```
LCD_write_String_to_Buffer("Esperando      \nconfiguracion...");
```

but what I get is:

[image]

I get like horizontal square brackets. Is there any way to remove all symbols and leave the space empty between "Esperando" and the "\n"?

I'm using `listings` with this syntax color:

```
\lstset{language=C++,
            keywordstyle=\color{RedViolet},
            stringstyle=\color{blue},
            commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
            morecomment=[l][\color{Orange}]{\#}
}
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are you using `listings` or any other package? Provide a minimal complete document illustrating the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How is this connected to LaTeX? What is `LCD_write_String_to_Buffer`?

Comment: I don't think this is TeX-related. Rather looks like Arduino...

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yes, I'm using `listings`

Comment: What you're getting there is a space character. This is the expected behaviour in some cases and environments and when using some packages. It can probably be turned off with an option or declaration. However, for us to know the cause - and the solution - we need a lot more information. TeX is pretty broad, there are lots of packages, lots of different uses for it, lots of variables. This why we always like to have an MWE (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: If you'd provided an MWE, we'd've known you were using `listings` and we could've got started on your problem straight away. Compiling an MWE may also have allowed you to diagnose and solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: seen it already... I will delete my comment then

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `showstringspaces=false`; either globally (for all your listings):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  showstringspaces=false,
  language=C++, 
  keywordstyle=\color{RedViolet}, 
  stringstyle=\color{blue}, 
  commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen}, 
  morecomment=[l][\color{Orange}]{\#},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
LCD_write_String_to_Buffer("Esperando      \nconfiguracion...");
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

or locally (for a particular one):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  language=C++, 
  keywordstyle=\color{RedViolet}, 
  stringstyle=\color{blue}, 
  commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen}, 
  morecomment=[l][\color{Orange}]{\#},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[showstringspaces=false]
LCD_write_String_to_Buffer("Esperando      \nconfiguracion...");
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The result in both cases:

[image]

Comment: that works, but in my case I'm using some syntax color:
`\lstset{language=C++,
                keywordstyle=\color{RedViolet},
                stringstyle=\color{blue},
                commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
                morecomment=[l][\color{Orange}]{\#}
}`
and in that case it wont work

Comment: @tulians And how do you expect me to guess that? Always provide *complete* minimal documents in your questions.

Comment: @tulians Please see my updated answer.

Comment: That worked great. Thanks for the answer and the patience.

Comment: @tulians You're new. Of course we can be patient, it takes time to learn how things are done when you first join a community. But I hope now you realise why we insist on MWEs. Not only could you have got your answer sooner, without needing to explain everything after writing your question; but you also sent Gonzalo Medina on a bit of a wild goose chase - causing him to waste a little of his own, spare time. So hopefully, now you know, next time you won't make a similar mistake :) In the meantime, read the tour http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour and earn a badge :)

Comment: @Au101 Such a nice comment. Thanks for writting it.